# linear algebra formulation help

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, block-matrices

I asked this on mathoverflow as well and apologies for cross-posting. I am trying to compute this so-called bending energy matrix. The bending energy of a thin plate in 3D is given by:

$$
BE = \int_0^{X}\int_0^{Y}\int_0^{Z} \sum_{d=1}^{3}\left\{\left(\frac{\partial^2u_d}{\partial x^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial^2u_d}{\partial y^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial^2u_d}{\partial z^2}\right)^2 + 2\left[\left(\frac{\partial^2u_d}{\partial x \partial y}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial^2u_d}{\partial x \partial dz}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial^2u_d}{\partial y \partial z}\right)^2\right]\right\}dx dy dz
$$

Now, I am trying to embed this so that the above equation would be equal to

$$
BE = u'\Sigma u
$$

where u would be a vector that defines the components of the field $u_d$ in the bending energy equation. Now, I need to find this matrix $\Sigma$ so that the above equality can be specified. This should be a large and sparse matrix. However, I have been struggling all day to formulate the form of this matrix and what it's entries should be. I was hoping someone here might give me some pointers on how to construct this matrix.

I would really appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: based on the dimensionality of function $u(x,y,z)$, it seems like $\Sigma$ should be a $3\times3$ matrix, so by "large" you are referring to the coefficients of element of $\Sigma$?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess it would be made of blocks of certain sizes. So, ultimately I think $\sigma$ would be of a symmetric sparse matrix of n x n x 3 where n is the length of the vector u? I also made a mistake in my latex which I corrected now and added the '+' sign for the diagonal terms!

Comment: I'm still confused, so the $u$ in $u^T\Sigma u$ is different than the functions $u_d(x,y,z)$? right? and are you missing $dxdydz$ in the integral?

Comment: yes, sorry about the missing infinitesimals. I am a self-learner and just started to do calculus and am a bit green. The $u$ in the two equations are the same. The $u$ in the second equation can be interpreted as putting each of the individual $u$s from the first equation into a big vector.

Comment: well then $u_d$ is a vector function? then $\frac{\partial^2u_d}{\partial x^2}$,... will be tensors, aren't you missing any thing?

Comment: $u_d$ is a function that takes a 3D point (a vector quantity) and outputs a scalar. The output of the second equation would be a vector whose squared norm would be the bending energy from the first equation. The first equation results in a scalar, as far as I understood it.

Comment: 1- You mean: $u(x,y,z)=[u_1(x,y,z),u_2(x,y,z),u_3(x,y,z)]^T$ (this shouldn't be the case, because then $\Sigma$ would be $3\times 3$ and BE would be a function of $(x,y,z)$),  2- do you know the parametrization of $u_d$'s as a function of $(x,y,z)$

Comment: hmmmmmm…. I am not sure what you mean. I am sorry I am not very good at maths, especially employing the right syntax. So basically $u_{d)$ is defined at every single $(x,y,z)$ over a region. Every measurement of $(x,y,z)$ has an associated $u$. Think of it like a 3D picture where each pixel has an associated intensity.

Comment: Then, the problem is that BE in the first equation is not a function of a single point but in the second equation it is! Therefore, you are missing something in your formulation. I think what I'm missing is: 1- What exactly is the shape of $u$? 2- What function of $(x,y,z)$, $u_d$'s are? unless you want to solve a calculus of variations problem.

Comment: So, if we imagine $u$ as a vector field than in the second equation one can imagine $u$ as a stacked one dimensional vector. So, $u$ can be something like ${x_1, X_2, X_3…., y_1, y_2, y_3…., z_1, z_2, z_3)$. In that case $u'\Sigma u$ will return a vector and the idea is that the squared norm of this vector should give the BE. $u_{d)$ refers to the component of the $u$ vector in that dimension.

Comment: I, of course, made another error in the explanation. So, $u(x, y, z) returns a vector with 3 components and $u(d)$ where d is either x, y or z…refers to that component of the vector...